# What is the difference between `lookup.unreflect()` and `lookup.findVirtual()`?

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

There are 2 ways i have tried to obtain the MethodHandle to a given function.

> Method 1

```
Method m = MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod", String.class, Map.class);
MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(m);
```

> Method 2

```
MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class, Map.class);
MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().findVirtual(MyClass.class, "myMethod", type);
```

What is the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, `unreflect` *has* a resolved method already, therefore doesn’t need to do a lookup. Also, it’s output depends on the `Method` you provide, a `static` method will yield a handle invoking the `static` method while `findVirtual` explicitly request a *virtual* method invocation. Keep in mind that `MyClass.class.getMethod("myMethod", String.class, Map.class)` might also find a `static` method accepting a `String` and a `Map`.

Further, if `setAccessible(true)` has been applied to the `Method` instance, you may get a handle accessing an otherwise inaccessible method which is not possible using `findVirtual`.

On the other hand, `findVirtual` may find appropriately typed invocations of the *signature polymorphic* methods `MethodHandle.invoke` and `MethodHandle.invokeExact` which can’t be accessed via `java.lang.reflect.Method`.

Comment: [`MethodHandle.invokeExact`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact-java.lang.Object...-) can be invoked with arbitrary arguments which must match the underlying target method. So you can use `lookup().findVirtual(MethodHandle.class, "invokeExact", arbitraryType)` to do the same reflectively. In contrast, `MethodHandle.class .getMethod("invokeExact", …)` only works with `Object[].class` as argument and invoking it will always produce an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: went above my head @Holger (i am new to reflection). But, thanks for the answer. `unreflect` appears to be good choice because i want to work with static methods as well. (why would you use `findVirtual` on `MethodHandle` itself?)

Comment: Using `findVirtual(MethodHandle.class, "invokeExact", MethodType.methodType(ret, args))` yields a new handle having the type `(MethodHandle, args)ret`, in other words takes the actual target handle as its first argument and can call different handles with compatible signatures. This can be a starting point to build switches like [`MethodHandles.guardWithTest(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#guardWithTest-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-) but with more than two handles…

Comment: [`MethodHandles.exactInvoker(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#exactInvoker-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) describes another use case.

Comment: why can we not simply use `methodHandle.invokeExact(args);` instead of `encapsulatorMethodHandle.invokeExact(methodHandle, args);`. in both cases, anyway you need to create `methodHandle` pointing to a specific method. i couldn't really understand `MethodHandles.guardWithtest()` or `MethodHandles.exactInvoker()`. Thanks.

Comment: Because the method in question might not be supposed to do the actual invocation but to return a handle for later use. One typical case would be the bootstrap method of an `invokedynamic` instruction.